# unix or perl one liner for tailing more than one file at the same time

Tags: perl, unix

Can someone help me come up with a quick unix or perl one liner to tail Xn of logs at the same time?
I just need to quickly view 2 or more logs on stdout, enough lines to view on my screen.

I am using `tail -30 filename_1.out` for example, but have to arrow up and change the 1->2->3. But I really want to do is tail a couple of few of them in one pass, if the filenames were `filename_1.out`,`filename_2.out`, `filename_3.out`

Answer (score 5):

`tail` can be given many files at once; try

```
tail -30 filename_[123].out
```

Comment: thanks. i can't pass -30, but it works with the default `tail filename_[123.out]`

Comment: @jdamae: can you use `tail -n 30 filename_[123].out` ?

Answer (score 2):

If

```
tail -30 filename_*.out
```

wouldn't work on a particular version of the userland tools (?) then you could always do:

```
(for a in filename*.out; do tail -f "$a"& done) | tail -f
```

e.g. to follow the tail

Answer (score 1):

If you operating system supports it use [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) - this does exactly what you want.